# trigger a jquery .load when a listbox item is selected

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, listbox

I am trying to make a jquery .load to occur when I make a selection from a listbox. I cannot get the following code to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#list1").change(function() {
        $("#resultdiv").load("myphproutine.php");
   });
});

<select id="list1">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

myphproutine.php is

```
<?php
    echo "Calculating";
?>
```

Comment: How does the code fail?  Is the event handler attached to the element?  Is the event handler executed when the element's selection changes?  Is the AJAX request performed?  What is the server's response?  Where *specifically* does the problem occur?

Comment: I get no response from myphproutine.php which is only one line echo "calculating";

Comment: What does not work? Th code is working on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eaL48dns/). Do you get errors?

Comment: What do you mean by `listbox`?

Comment: @user3242716: Define "no response".  When you debug this in your browser, what is the actual response from the server?  Does it truly not respond at all and the browser just times out?  There's nothing wrong with the code you posted.  If something isn't behaving as you expect, you need to provide us with at least *some* debugging information.

Comment: I have simplified the code to what you see just to get myphproutine.php to fire, but I select an option and nothing happens.

Comment: the <div id="resultdiv"></div> is not loaded with "Calculating"

Comment: @user3242716 ar you running this on server , or localhost ?

Comment: I am using jquery-1.4.2.js

Comment: If the code looks good, then it's got to be me.  I'll keep checking.

Comment: @user3242716 try to echo some div instead of a string.